# What if access control rule defined for participant/asset contradicts access control rule for transaction?

Tags: access-control, hyperledger-composer

I have a question regarding access control.

Specifically, the question is about the relationship between access control rules defined for participants or assets on the one hand and asset control rules defined for transactions accessing those participants/assets.

Here is an example:

Assume a Hyperledger Fabric network is used to create some kind of social network for employees of a company.

The following rule states that an employee has write access to his own data:

```
rule EmployeesHaveWriteAccessToTheirOwnData {
    description: "Allow employees write access to their own data"
    participant(p): "org.company.biznet.Employee"
    operation: UPDATE
    resource(r): "org.company.biznet.Employee"
    condition: (p.getIdentifier() == r.getIdentifier())
    action: ALLOW
}
```

Let's assume that the write access is facilitated through a transaction called "UpdateTransaction". Further assume that (maybe by accident) the action value of the access control rule of transaction "UpdateTransaction" is set to "Denied"

```
rule EmployeeCanSubmitTransactionsToUpdateData {
    description: "Allow employees to update their data"
    participant: "org.company.biznet.Employee"
    operation: CREATE
    resource: "org.company.biznet.UpdateTransaction"
    action: Denied
}
```

Now there is the following situation:

Each employee is (through rule 1) given the right to change his/her data.
At the same time employees are not allowed to submit the transaction "UpdateTransaction" to change the data (see rule 2).

Is it now impossible for employees to change their data? Or are employees still able to change their data without submitting the transaction "UpdateTransaction"?

Put differently: is there a way for participants to access data (for which they have access rights) without using any of the transactions defined in the .cto-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is, it depends.

In your example, denying access to the *org.company.biznet.UpdateTransaction* transaction would result in *org.company.biznet.Employee* participants being unable to use that transaction to update their data, even though they would otherwise be allowed.

Having said that, you should keep the system transactions in mind since they provide another potential route for *org.company.biznet.Employee* participants to update their own data.

For example, I tried that out on the *basic-sample-network* by replacing the *EverybodyCanSubmitTransactions* rule with

```
rule NobodyCanSubmitTransactions {
    description: "Do not allow all participants to submit transactions"
    participant: "org.example.basic.SampleParticipant"
    operation: CREATE
    resource: "org.example.basic.SampleTransaction"
    action: DENY
}
```

That business network includes an *OwnerHasFullAccessToTheirAssets* rule and I was able to use the *org.hyperledger.composer.system.UpdateAsset* transaction to make updates for participants that owned an asset using the command,

```
composer transaction submit -d "$(cat txn.json)" -c party1@basic-sample-network
```

Where txn.json contained,

```
{
  "$class": "org.hyperledger.composer.system.UpdateAsset",
  "resources": [
    {
      "$class": "org.example.basic.SampleAsset",
      "assetId": "ASSET1",
      "owner": "resource:org.example.basic.SampleParticipant#PARTY1",
      "value": "5000"
    }
  ],
  "targetRegistry": "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AssetRegistry#org.example.basic.SampleAsset"
}
```

That wouldn't work if you had locked down the system namespace in your ACL rules though. (ACLs need a lot of thought!)

The other important thing to remember about ACLs is that they do not apply if you use the *getNativeAPI* method to access data via the Hyperledger Fabric APIs in your transaction processor functions.

Check out the [system namespace reference](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/systemns/systemns-index) along with the [ACL reference](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/acl_language), plus there is an [ACL tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/acl-trading) which may be of interest if you haven't seen it.